# How to remove a character nested in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, character, nested-lists, del

I am given a sample string `AABCAAADA`. I then split it into 3 parts: `AAB`, `CAA`, `ADA`.
I have nested these 3 elements into a list. In each part, I should check whether a duplicate character is present and delete the duplicate character. I know strings are immutable, but is there any trick to do that?

Below is the sample approach I tried but I am unable to use del and pop method to delete that duplicate character.

```
s='AABCAAADA'
x = int(input())
l=[]
#for i in range(0,len(s),x):
for j in range(0,len(s),3):
    l.append(s[j:j+3])

j=0
for i in range(0,len(s)//x):
    for j in range(0,len(l[j])-1):
        if(l[i][j] == l[i][j+1]):
            pass
          #need to remove the (j+1)th term if it is duplicate
```

The output should be `AB`, `CA`, `AD`.

[delete duplicate character in nested list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W9WT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
l = ['AAB','CAA','ADA']
print([''.join(reduce(lambda a, b: a if b in a else a + b, s, '')) for s in l])
```

Or, for Python 3.6+:

```
print([''.join({a: 1 for a in s}) for s in l])
```

Both output:

```
['AB', 'CA', 'AD']
```

Comment: is there a way to do using my logic ?

Comment: Can you please explain [''.join({a: 1 for a in s}) for s in l]) ?

Comment: Is there a way to deal with individual characters present nested in list ? Like we do in C?

Comment: Your logic is off quite a bit unfortunately so it's hard to make it work without completely rewriting most of it. The second method I used takes advantage of the fact that in Python 3.6+ dicts are always ordered in the same way its items are added, so by using characters as keys of the dict comprehension, not only the latter duplicating characters are discarded because the earlier ones prevail, the order of the keys is also preserved when the dict is converted to a list when passed to `str.join`.

Comment: To change an individual character in a string, you would have to slice it. For example, if `a = 'abcde'` and you want to change its third character to `'x'` you can do `a = a[:2] + 'x' + a[3:]`.

Comment: Or, you can cast the string to a list, alter it, and then convert the list to a string using `str.join`. For example, `l = list(a); l[2] = 'x'; a = ''.join(l)`.